# Significato di "incocciare" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nel romanzo *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Totonno, ogni mattina immancabile a quest’ora, come un appuntamento, con qualsiasi tempo. Mai visto uno che rema seduto così, faccia alla prua, e con le gambe piegate sotto, come se stesse in ginocchio. Troppo piccola quella barca per lui. Dice che è comoda, ma voglio vede’ col maltempo, se l’**incoccia**. Una sedia a rotelle, la manovra così, tutto di braccia, con quei remi corti.

Per si è d'aiuto, il romanzo è ambientato a Napoli.

Ho cercato il verbo ["incocciare" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/incocciare/) e su qualche altro dizionario, ma non riesco a vedere quale significato possa avere nel testo. La frase dove appare si potrebbe qualificare di parlare colloquiale? Cosa vuol dire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probabilmente  il senso di “incocciare” usato nel testo di La Capria  è quello citato da Teccani.it al punto 3a:

> imbattersi in persona o cosa. (Uso familiare e regionale  centro/sud)

Il senso della frase sarebbe:

> - “voglio vedere come se la cava col maltempo, se ci si imbatte in barca.”

Comment: Ho fatto una piccola modifica che, ovviamente, puoi "rollback" se non ti sembra bene. Mi pare importante che appaia "familiare" perché è qualcosa che in certo modo chiedo nella domanda. Poi, da quanto ho capito io leggendo alcuni libri, "regionale" e "dialettale" non sono esattamente la stessa cosa. Il Treccani usa l'abbreviazione "dial." per "dialettale". Come fanno parecchi dizionari, quando si tratta di un uso regionale utilizza delle abbreviazioni per indicare l'ambito geografico di uso.

Comment: Non c’è problema, anche se non mi è molto chiaro cosa intendono per “familiare”. Per questo non l’avevo citato.

Comment: È spiegato qui:  https://dizionaripiu.zanichelli.it/lingua-e-scuola/posta-del-professore/marche-duso-colloquiale-non-e-familiare/.

Comment: Appunto, non mi sembra si tratti di una locuzione “riservata allo stretto giro di parenti  e amici” ma più diffusa. Infatti è usata e capita nel centro e sud d’Italia.

Comment: Usata nel centro e sud d'Italia, ma che, secondo il dizionario, probabilmente non si userebbe parlando con uno sconosciuto. Le due marche d'uso non sono escludenti.

Comment: Qualcuno ha delle informazioni sull'uso di questa parola (magari per averla sentito usare spesso)? Gli usi della lingua si evolvono spesso più veloci di quanto riportano i dizionari. Potrebbe essere che questa parola fosse sentita come di uso familiare anni fa e adesso non lo sia più. (Non so come interpretare gli upvote ai commenti.)

Comment: Un esempio di termine marcato dal dizionario come di uso familiare è "tetta", di cui si era parlato [qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/13028/) (anche in catalano e in castigliano esiste "teta" con usi molto simili): è usato e capito in tutta Italia, ma io non l'userei mai parlando con una persona che non conosco molto bene o non posso immaginare il mio medico usandolo parlando con me. "Familiare" significa appunto questo. Poi, le parole sempre possono essere adoperate in situazioni in cui uno non se le aspetta, e quando accade con questa parola diventa volgare.

Comment: La mia impressione è che la distinzione è del colloquiale vs familiare che fa lo Zanichelli sua molto debole. Tutte le espressioni citate, tranne “briscola” (forse un regionalismo) sono comunemente usate in ambito informale per cui sono espressioni  colloquiali, non ci vedo nulla di “familiare“. Tetta ad esempio, io non la userei in famiglia, ma piuttosto con estranei.